# blender 2.93 light will not work

Tags: rendering, lighting

my copy of blender is not working with light.
i am taking a tutorial where you have to get the light to light  a table. when ever i go to viewport shading my object turns  A dark gray. ive tried adding a texture to it and so far it just shows A Gray color unshaded. i don't know if something is wrong with my graphics or what it could be . i don't know what to do. is it my computer that's the problem? does anyone know how to get lighting to work when an object turns gray? [image: it wont light]

Answer (score 0):

[image: viewport shading]

In the (material preview) viewport shading you can check the little arrow on the left. You can check the scene lights and the scene world. The viewport render then will use the lights in the scene and the world settings of the scene.